# If you don't reply for the next three hours

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Imagine I told you something like:

> If you don't reply for the next 3 hours, I will stop talking to you.

What would you think the meaning was? Do you think it would be

> - If you don't keep replying for the next 3 hours I will stop talking to you. or >- If you don't reply sometime between those 3 hours, I'll stop talking to you.

Is it just a matter of emphasis? E.g.:

> - If you **don't reply** for the next 3 hours, I will stop talking to you.
> - If you don't **reply for the next 3 hours**. I will stop talking to you.

Answer (score 3):

> If you don't reply for the next 3 hours, I will stop talking to you.

Means, *if you don't keep replying the next 3 hours...*, e.g. give you replies for three hours straight.

> *[For](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for)*: used to indicate amount, extent, or duration: a bill for five dollars; walked for miles; stood in line **for an hour.** (TFD)

If you want a reply, as in *"If you don't reply sometime during those 3 hours*", it would be correct to say,

> If you don't reply *in* the next 3 hours...*

Emphasis has nothing to do with it. It is a matter of correct word choice.

Comment: I disagree with the first paragraph. "If you don't reply for the next 3 hours" does not mean "if you don't keep replying". It means "if you keep not replying". Huge difference. (In fact, I struggle to think of a scenario in which "reply" *could* mean "keep replying". It just doesn't work that way. You *have* to say "keep replying" to get that meaning.)

Comment: IMO, of your examples, "if you don't reply *in* the next three hours" is the most common way to state that a reply should be received within that 3-hour window of time.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - of "my" examples? It was the only answer I gave.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - I am a native (AmE) speaker and have never heard the structure given. If someone said *for the next 3 hours*, I would understand, but would not think it correct.

Comment: Sorry @medica, I was confused by all the shaded sections.  In any event, I agreed with you and gave a +1. :-)